# ImportError using Crontab

Tags: python, shell, cron, sh, importerror

I'm trying to run a python script automatically via crontab on Mac.

```
25 12 * * * sh  /Users/simonwe/PycharmProjects/crawlerzon/crawler.sh
```

The scripts looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

export PYTHONPATH=/Users/simonwe/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
python /Users/simonwe/PycharmProjects/crawlerzon/crawler.py
```

When I run it manually in terminal everything works fine, but in crontab it gives me this Error:

```
From simonwe@Simons-iMac.local  Wed Aug 19 12:25:02 2020
X-Original-To: simonwe
Delivered-To: simonwe@Simons-iMac.local
From: simonwe@Simons-iMac.local (Cron Daemon)
To: simonwe@Simons-iMac.local
Subject: Cron <simonwe@Simons-iMac> sh  /Users/simonwe/PycharmProjects/crawlerzon/crawler.sh
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=simonwe>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=simonwe>
Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2020 12:25:01 +0200 (CEST)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/simonwe/PycharmProjects/crawlerzon/crawler.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I also tried running the .py file specifying the Path of the interpreter im using.

```
00 13 * * * /Users/simonwe/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/simonwe/PycharmProjects/crawlerzon/crawler.py
```

but I seems to ignore the command entirely.

I found similar questions but tried all the answers:

Happy for your advise!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full python path.

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/simonwe/PycharmProjects/crawlerzon/crawler.py
```

To find out where python is
`where python` to find your python.

But, my doubt here is that you have multiple pythons. And you have to point to the right one.

If you're still not sure, just list the pythons packages of each python you have using.

`python -c 'help("modules")'`

And then run your python, with correct one.

Because as I see above, you have a **default python** installed and an **anaconda python** as well. So by default, your code will point to the Linux python2.7 by default.  That's the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I also figured that the different python versions are the problem here.

I just realized that running the .py file like I did works just finde, but crontab saves the files in a different directory than if I run it manually:

Comment: Then, change directory and run your file. If the program saves your file in current working directory. Use a ```cd /path/to/your/directory/``` in *.sh file and try it out.